# How to convert time given as string into integer mins

Tags: mysql, sql

What I'm trying to ask is that I've a table *Duration*. It has only one field *elapsed* and it is VARCHAR. The table is this:

```
+-----------------+
|     elapsed     |
+-----------------+
| 30 min          |
| 30 min          |
| 1 hour          |
| 1 hour          |
| 1 hour 30 min   |
| 1 hour 30 min   |
+-----------------+
```

I want this table:

```
+------------------------+
| elapsed         |total |
+------------------------+
| 30 min          | 30   |
| 30 min          | 30   |
| 1 hour          | 60   |
| 1 hour          | 60   |
| 1 hour 30 min   | 90   |
| 1 hour 30 min   | 90   |
+-----------------+------+
```

*total* should be integer or number. I've to perform some arithmetic on it later.

Here's what I tried:

```
case
WHEN substring_index(pa.Duration, 'hour', 1) > 0 and not substring_index(pa.Duration, 'min', 1) > 0
then cast(concat(pa.Duration,concat(' ' , 1)) as signed) * 60
WHEN substring_index(pa.Duration, 'hour', 1) > 0 and substring_index(pa.Duration, 'min', 1) > 0
then (cast(concat(pa.Duration,concat(' ' , 1)) as signed) * 60 + cast(concat(pa.Duration,concat(' ' , 3)) as signed) )
WHEN not substring_index(pa.Duration, 'hour', 1) > 0 and substring_index(pa.Duration, 'min', 1) > 0
then cast(concat(pa.Duration,concat(' ' , 1)) as signed)
else 0 end as minutes
```

Please help me.

**Note:** I need MYSQL query not MSSQL.

Comment: Consider changing the schema and just storing the minutes as an (unsigned?) `integer`. You can do the formatting into a human (better) readable string when needed. The disadvantage when storing it as a `varchar` is, next to the necessity of parsing it when you want to do arithmetic on it, that you don't have to take extra care of garbage being inserted. E.g. `'mix 2 bananas and 3 1/2 apples'` is a valid `varchar` but not a valid duration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only have `min` and `hour`, you can use:

```
select elapsed, 
       ((case when elapsed like '% hour%'
              then substring_index(elapsed, ' hour', 1) * 60
              else 0
         end) +
        (case when elapsed like '%min%'
              then substring_index(substring_index(elapsed, ' min', 1), ' ', -1) + 0
              else 0
         end)
        ) as elapsed_minutes
from t;
```

This extracts the number before "hour" if any, multiplies by 60 and adds in the number before "minute", if any.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a6fb9e88cd87d69964258b21a2a492e9) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Please explain the logic little bit :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since there are only 3 possibilities for the values of the column `elapsed`:

- hours and mins
- only hours
- only mins

you can use a `CASE` expression and MySql's implicit conversions of strings to numbers:

```
SELECT 
  elapsed,
  CASE
    WHEN elapsed LIKE '% hour % min' THEN 60 * elapsed + SUBSTRING_INDEX(elapsed, ' ', -2)
    WHEN elapsed LIKE '% hour' THEN 60 * elapsed 
    WHEN elapsed LIKE '% min' THEN elapsed + 0
  END total
FROM tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4e78c64622e3642bd79f17dfedc060f2).
Results:

```
> elapsed       | total
> :------------ | ----:
> 30 min        |    30
> 30 min        |    30
> 1 hour        |    60
> 1 hour        |    60
> 1 hour 30 min |    90
> 1 hour 30 min |    90
```

Comment: That is why I prefer your answers. They are always crisp, clear and to the point. :-)